# How to filter articles that are in front page with taxonomy

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms, views

i have made quick moqup of the site to explain it better :

[image]

At this moment i made site in drupal 8 that has some articles in it and thous articles are shown in front page (landing Page).

I have made new taxonomy -> vocabulary -> and Add 4 term as shown in picture.

I have created new region and placed it in the front page and from views i call all articles that i have...

My problem is that, how to filter thous articles accordingly to the taxonomy and if there is possible not to refresh page (if Can't than there is no problem)...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a views filter using the taxonomy field of your article and expose it.

[image]

If you don't want the page to refresh then turn on "Use Ajax":

[image]

I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but could you be more analytic of what should i do? i am not good at drupal at this moment....

Comment: I assume you have already made your view filtering on content type "Article"? And that you are already displaying it on the front page?
Just go back to that view and add a new filter under "filter criteria" in the bottom left of the view admin UI. Pick the taxonomy field you use in your article content type. For example, if the field is called field_category, search for that field when adding a filter.

Comment: aaa OK i get your point... but doing so, I would have only filtered article by one taxonomy criteria in a view... I want to have them all and by the clicking the  buttons that i have  in moqup in the center of a page i want to filter the article by the taxonomy criteria... (by the way can i have multiple views in a view? if i can than the problem is solved i could use 4 different views with filtered by taxonomy criteria and show them in one view in a front page)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, have you solved it yet? It is indeed possible to create 4 different displays in a view. You could just render each view block under each tab. This will be harder on your database since they will all load at the same time, but if we aren't talking about a lot of data it should be minor.

Comment: yes i solved it.... i made entirely different solution... i made 4 twig files for  each taxonomy term and made also 4 views with 4 different URLs and by hitting thous URLs i get filtered articles by taxonomy term. I know this solution is not ideal but it works for now.